# Mod-rewrite for css, js, html and directories in Apache/PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using mod_rewrite in .htaccess. I can't figure out how to get the following done.

- All css pages should go to `/minify/?f=/styles.css`
- All js pages should go to `/minify/?f=/js.js`
- All `.txt`, `.gif`, `.jpg`, `.png` files should open as they are
- All other pages (eg: `/page`, `/dir/page`, `/dir1/dir2/page`) should go to `/page.php`
- All other files in directories should open as it is (eg: `/admin/login.php`)

**Edit:**
This is the code that I came up with. It's not elegant, and it fails sometimes. For eg: I can't get `/admin/login.php` to work. When I open that URL, it's going to `page.php`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.txt)$
RewriteRule .* page.php
RewriteRule ^.*?\.css$ /min/?f=/styles.css [L]
RewriteRule ^.*?\.js$ /min/?f=/js.js [L]
```

Comment: Great. So anything you actually tried besides writing a list of requirements? How does your .htaccess look and where / how exactly does it fail? What ressources did you consult?

Comment: Apologies. I pasted the code that I came up with so far. It's not elegant and /admin/... pages don't work. I am hoping that you guys can help me with something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|txt|gif|jpe?g)$
RewriteRule ^ /page.php [L]

RewriteRule \.css$ /minify/?f=/styles.css [NE,L]
RewriteRule \.(js)$ /minify/?f=/$1.$1 [NE,L]
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's working fine for all the URLs, except /. I get 403 Forbidden error for http:// website and http:// website/. It's working for http:// website/dir urls though.

Comment: @Castortroy The 403 is raised by something else.

Comment: I don't have a index.php file. It should also go to page.php. I removed all the code from the .htaccess and tried and it still throws 403 forbidden. So, I am guessing it's because of lack of a index file, but I do want them to be sent to page.php

Comment: You can add a custom rule @Castortroy like: `RewriteRule ^/?$ /page.php [L]`

Comment: Perfect !! You are a savior